# zookeeper automatic start operation fails when firewall is stopped at rc.local script

Tags: hadoop, centos

iam using hadoop apache 2.7.1 on centos 7 
and my cluster is  ha cluster and  iam using zookeeper quorum for automatic failover

but i want to automate zookeeper start process and ofcourse in the shell script we have to stop firewall first in order to let other quorum elements able to contact current zookeeper element

iam  writing the following script in /etc/rc.d/rc.local

```
hostname jn1

systemctl stop firewalld

ZOOKEEPER='/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.9/'
source /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

source $ZOOKEEPER/bin/zkEnv.sh

daemon --user root $ZOOKEEPER/bin/zkServer.sh start
```

but iam facing the problem that when iam issuing the command

`systemctl stop firewalld` 
in rc.local

and issuing zkServer status after host boots  iam getting the error

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

but if i execute the  same commands with out a script i mean after my host boots as normal process

```
systemctl status firewalld

zkServer start
```

there is no problem and zkstatus shows its mode

i have noticed the difference in zookeeper.out log between executing  rc.local script and normal commands after the host boots

and the difference is  reading server environments in normal commands execute

what could be the effect of stopping firewall at rc.local script to server environment and how to handle it 
?

Comment: Are there any more commands before hostname jn1 in rc.local ? After booting up system is firewalld running ?

Comment: no these are the only commands ,after booting system firewalld is not running

Comment: is rc.local file a good place to put systemctl stop firewalld command and are firewall required variables loaded well in rc.local before we can stop it

Comment: i think the operation iam doing is fake firewall stopping ,is not it?\

Answer (score 0):

i have abig headache about stopping and restarting firewall scenarios

and i discovered that stopping firewall at rc.local is a fake stopping

so because idon't want fire wall to work at all i ended up with the following solution

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-disable-the-firewall-in-centos-7-linux/

so firewall is not going to work again at any boot